# SSJS failed to process 500K records

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs, automationstudio

The script activity is getting timeout while processing 500K records. I have 2 data extensions.

First data extension: Contains the 10 programs mapped to each account numbers. Account number is primary key. This data extension has 500K records
`AccountNumber|Programid1|Programid2|Programid3|Programid4|Programid5.......|programid10`

Second data extension: It has information about programs. Program id is primary key. This de has 200 records
`Programid|Image|URL|Description|Title|Hidden`

Outcome: Fetch first 4 matching programs from first DE for each account number, which exists in second de and has Hidden Boolean flag false.
Output DE:
`AccountNumber|Programid1|Programid2|Programid3|Programid4`

I know the script activity timeout after 30 min and processing 500K records within 30 min is not possible. Is there any other approach that can used to process records. The one approach I could think of is to process these records in batches by duplicating script activity multiple times in the automation but this approach is not sustainable as the record count can increase from 500K records to 1000K in future.

Comment: Can you help me with query. I mean the first de has account number as the primary key and second de has program id as primary key. how will i join these two de. Also how can i achieve loop kind of functionality in queries.

Comment: The output of the query should be AccountNumber|ProgramID1|programID2|ProgramID3|ProgramId4. The intend is to fetch the top 4 matching program id's out of 10 programs id for each account that matches to second DE.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to show all the four program IDs with thier respective details in the email.